# hibernate persist two objects simultaneously

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, persistence

I have two objects which have OneToOne relation between them: **Project** and **Donation**. **Project** object relays some logic to **Donation** object that is situated inside **Project** object (*donations* table shopuld be filled when *projects* is filled).My aim is to make **Donation** object to be persisted when **Project** is persisted. My classes:

**Project.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="projects")
public class Project{

    private int id;
    private String name;

    public Donation donation;

    public Project() {}

    public Project(String name, Donation donation) {
        this.name = name;
        this.donation = donation;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="project_id")
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    @Column(name="project_name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "project_id")
    public DonationLogic getDonation() {
        return donation;
    }

    public void setDonation(DonationLogic donation) {
        this.donation = donation;
    }
}
```

**Donation.class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="donations")
public class Donation {
    private int totalAmount;
    private int daysLeft;
    private double collectAmount;
    private int id;
    private Project project;

    public Donation() {}

    public Donation(int totalAmount, int daysLeft) {
        if(totalAmount <= 0 || daysLeft <= 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        this.totalAmount = totalAmount;
        this.daysLeft = daysLeft;
        this.collectAmount = 0.0;
    }

    public Donation(int totalAmount, int daysLeft, double collectedamount) {
        if(totalAmount <= 0 || daysLeft <= 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        this.totalAmount = totalAmount;
        this.daysLeft = daysLeft;
        this.collectAmount = collectedamount;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="donation_id")
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="donation_project_id")
    public Project getProject() {
        return project;
    }

public void setProject(Project project) {
        this.project = project;
    }
//other getters/ setters
}
```

Here I want to persist **Project** but with **Donation** as well. But for now it does not work((( Only *projects* table is filled. Not *donations* table. Is it possible to persist them simultaneously - *donations* table filled when *projects* filled?

**Main.java**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("application-context.xml");
        SessionFactory sessionfactory = (SessionFactory) context.getBean("sessionFactory");
        Session session = sessionfactory.getCurrentSession();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        Donation donation = new Donation(10000, 50);
        Project project1 = new Project("sport arena", "arena in Kiev",  donation);
        session.persist(project1);//only projects table is persisted. Not donations. 
}
```

In *donations* table foreign key is column *donation_project_id*. In *projects* - primary key *project_id*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add cascade type to your annotation like this :

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
@JoinColumn(name = "project_id")
public DonationLogic getDonation() {
    return donation;
}
```

[Hibernate documentation about it](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/entity.html#entity-hibspec-cascade)

**UPDATE:**

In a bi-directional association, one side of the of the relation must own the association. [This is a good example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10687529/onetoone-bidirectional-mapping-with-joincolumn).

Comment: Thanks Bill. It almost works. However donation_project_id column is somehow null((( I can not fill foreign key((

Comment: I updated my answer, if you don't get it, I'll write the code.

Comment: No, I get you answer. I just have a problem that donation_project_id from donations table is null.

Comment: Read the link. in a OneToOne relation, you can use a shared primary key (@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn). Or, use just one foreign key in the side of the relation that owns the relation which means the second joinColumn is not needed and you should remove @JoinColumn(name="donation_project_id") and add mappedBy.

Comment: But, what if I need not bidirectional relation but only from projects to donations? I put OneToOne on Donation class just to make it somehow work.

Comment: If you only need the relation Project to Donation, make a unidirectional and remove `private Project project;` from donation class.