# JPA OneToOne relation automatic creation

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-boot, one-to-one

I fear this may have been asked before but I'm either not finding or not understanding the answer to similar questions.

I have this one table offerte

```
@Entity
public class Offerte extends BaseEntity{

    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="dossier")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @NotNull
    private Dossier dossier;
```

That has a OneToOne connection to the table dossier and upon creation of an offerte I want there to automatically be a dossier created.

```
@Entity
public class Dossier extends BaseEntity{

    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="dossier")
    @NotNull
    private Offerte offerte;
```

I've tried to do this with the generationtype auto but I keep gettin the violation

```
List of constraint violations:[
ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='may not be null',
```

Is it possible to make this relationship automatically valid?

**EDIT**

river's proposed java solution

```
@Entity
public class Offerte extends BaseEntity{
    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="dossier")
    @NotNull
    private Dossier dossier = new Dossier();
```

gives the following error

```
javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Validation failed for classes [be.ugent.lca.data.entities.Dossier] during persist time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]
List of constraint violations:[
ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='may not be null', propertyPath=offerte, rootBeanClass=class be.ugent.lca.data.entities.Dossier, messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message}'}
]
```

Comment: Could you please describe related tables with column names?

Comment: How do you mean exactly, the @Column(name="dossier,... annotation? cause that wasn't allowed with a @OneToOne relationship. Also the 2 column names for this relationship are just dossier and offerte

Comment: GeneratedValue is illegal on a relation field ... it is for Long, Integer, String etc

Comment: Offerte is not a table .. it is a class. You don't post your persistence code, showing what you are trying to persist. If you have a 1-1 and the related object exists then you must either enable cascade or call persist on the related object also

Comment: I'm really knew to setting this up so I'm probably wrong on some fronts. The only setup code is the annotations you see. The rest is done by spring-boot, should I mention this in my question, tags?

Comment: YOU are responsible for creating related objects if you want that to happen. JPA will not do it for you; it just persists what is there - that would be in any basic JPA tutorial. And if you are using Spring then yes you should mention it

Comment: So my question whether it's possible is a no. So should I just update all references when I'm creating the first object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to have offerte created whenever you create new Dossier object - you should just drop down to java solution:

```
public class Dosier {
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @NotNull
    private Offerte offerte = new Offerte(....);
}
```

This will have following consequences:

- Whenever new Dosier object is created (by calling constructor) offerte variable will be populated as part of construction with new Offerte object.
- When you save Dosier created like that it will save offerte object (that's what cascade option is for)
- When you load created dossier - JPA will load offerte object and initialise dossier correctly

Comment: I want to do the inverse and get the error that this must be done before saving the object:  
org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: Not-null property references a transient value - transient instance must be saved before current operation : be.ugent.lca.data.entities.Offerte.dossier -> be.ugent.lca.data.entities.Dossier

Comment: Make sure that you added (cascade = CascadeType.ALL) to Offerte#dossier field.

Comment: Also please look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10687818/6529383) to help you with correct mapping of one-to-one association.