# Hibernate OneToOne bidirectional mapping with only one property being an entity

Tags: java, hibernate

Lets say i have 2 entities - Person and Car.

I know I can do bidirectional mapping like this:

```
@Entity
public class Person implements Serializable {

    @Id Integer id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "car_id")
    Car car;
}

@Entity
public class Car implements Serializable {

    @Id Integer id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "car")
    Person person;
}
```

inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10687818/5076801).

However I don't want to store whole Person entity in Car entity. I want Car to look something like this:

```
@Entity
public class Car implements Serializable {

    @Id Integer id;

    Integer person_id;
}
```

and still have bidirectional mapping between the two entities. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Well not really, because the bidirectional relationship exists when both entity **objects** reference eachother. So, you can't just have `person_id` in the `Car` class unless you set it for the `Car` instance upon creation.

Answer (score 0):

First thing, note that when you associate one entity with other,Then In database only id attribute of related entity is stored in table [Either same table in case of ManyToOne or JoinTable in case ManyToMany] as foreign key. So, From database point of view it is optimezed [No extra overhead apart from foreign key].

Now from Java OOP point of view, Your one entity contains other entity as a field. This is quiet helpful in actual application. However, If you don't want other related entity in all cases, then you can use lazy loading facility prpovided by JPA [By default fetch type is Lazy]. Meaning, When you fetch an object from database, it has null value for associated other object and is initialized when you actually use that object.

In your case, Person is owning entity and Car is owned entity and In database Person table has car id as foreign key. While Car has only id column, no person id as foreign key.