# Recurrsive loop on method call, unsure if it is related to mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm having some issues with my entity mapping on these objects. I don't get an exception but it seems like it goes into a recursive loop

```
public class LabResult  implements java.io.Serializable {

     private Long labResultId;
     private Customer customer;
     private LabResultUnprocessed labResultUnprocessed;

public LabResult(){
}

public LabResult(Long labResultId) {
    this.labResultId = labResultId;
}

public LabResult(Long labResultId, Customer customer, LabResultUnprocessed labResultUnprocessed) {
    this.labResultId = labResultId;
    this.customer = customer;
    this.labResultUnprocessed = labResultUnprocessed;
}

@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="labResult")
@JoinColumn(name="lab_result_id")
public LabResultUnprocessed getLabResultUnprocessed(){
    return labResultUnprocessed;
}
public void setLabResultUnprocessed(LabResultUnprocessed labResultUnprocessed) {
    this.labResultUnprocessed = labResultUnprocessed;
}
```

The next domain is LabResultUnprocessed

```
@Entity
@Table(name="lab_result_unprocessed"
,schema="public"
)
public class LabResultUnprocessed implements java.io.Serializable {

private LabResult labResult;
private Boolean processedFlag;

public LabResultUnprocessed() {

}

public LabResultUnprocessed(LabResult labResult, Boolean processedFlag) {
    this.labResult = labResult;
    this.processedFlag = processedFlag;
}

@Id
@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="lab_result_id")
public LabResult getLabResult() {
    return labResult;
}

public void setLabResult(LabResult labResult) {
    this.labResult = labResult;
}
```

Here is the LabResultUnprocessedRepository

```
public interface LabResultUnprocessedRepository extends CrudRepository<LabResult, String>{

@Query("select lru from LabResultUnprocessed lru "
        +" join fetch lru.labResult lr "
        +" where lru.labResult.labResultId = lr.labResultId "
        +" and lru.processedFlag = false")
List<LabResultUnprocessed> findAllByProcessedFlag();
```

In my service when I call this method it seems like it goes into a recursive loop and never hits my breakpoint which is on the actual method call in this 2nd line.

```
    List<LabResultUnprocessed> allUnprocessedResults = new ArrayList<LabResultUnprocessed>();
    allUnprocessedResults = labResultUnprocessedRepository.findAllByProcessedFlag();

    allUnprocessedResults.forEach(lru -> {
    ...////
```

Comment: The title of your question bears no resemblance to your actual question. What exactly is the error you see? I would guess it relates to the fact that you appear to have an Entity LabResult  which has no @Id field.

Comment: Sorry it is there - I just forgot to include the getters and setters for the other 2 properties in LabResult - Once the method labResultUnprocessedRepository.findAllByProcessedFlag(); is called - it goes into a recursive loop.

Comment: are you sure you have an infinite loop? Did you try to set hibernate so that queries are logged and if so, did you try running your query "by hand"? I also think that there's a @JoinColumn that should not be here, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10687529/onetoone-bidirectional-mapping-with-joincolumn

Comment: In my debugger - when i put a breakpoint at that line it shows an empty array before it actually gets the data - when i stepover to goto the forEach line - i get this in the variables window: [toString() unavailable - no suspended threads]

Comment: the query manually returns what I expect

Comment: Did you get a thread dump?  If its stuck or looping, obtaining one or more thread dumps are the only real way to tell where the process is and what it might be having problems with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems in this section:

```
@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="testResult")
@JoinColumn(name="test_result_id")
```

1. `mappedBy` and `@JoinColumn` don't go together. One end of the relationship should have one, and the other end should have the other. Neither end should have both. Remove `@JoinColumn` from this end to fix this.
2. The value of `mappedBy` needs to be the name of the field on the other end of the relationship - in this case, `labResult`.