# hibernate one to one relationship mapping, save only inserts child

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, sql-insert, one-to-one

I have the following relationship with person and transaction (one to one in my case). I want to be able to save a Person with a Transaction attached resulting in two inserts. One in tbl_person and one in tbl_Transaction. But the following only generates one insert instead of two. The one insert is in tbl_Transaction:

```
`CREATE TABLE `tbl_person` (
    `ID` char(36) NOT NULL,
    `TransactionID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
    UNIQUE KEY `TransactionID` (`TransactionID`),
    CONSTRAINT `tbl_person_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`TransactionID`) 
    REFERENCES `tbl_Transaction` (`TransactionID`)
);

CREATE TABLE `tbl_transaction` (
    `TransactionID` int(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`TransactionID`)
);

@Table(name="tbl_person")
@Entity
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@ToString
@Data
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "hibernate-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "hibernate-uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(name="ID", nullable = false)
    private String ID;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "transactionId")
    private Transaction transaction;
}

@Table(name="tbl_transaction")
@Entity
@Data
public class Transaction {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer transactionId;
}

public class Service() {
    public void saveTransaction(Transaction transaction) {
        Person person = new Person();
        person.setTransaction(transaction);
        getSessionCurrent().save(person);
    }
}
```

`

service.saveTransaction(transaction);

The service.saveTransaction returns with no exception but it only inserts the transaction but not the person.

Can any one tell me what I am doing wrong ??

Comment: Your code wouldn't compile. Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you need to define a @OneToOne field in Transaction class
like specified in this question:
[@OneToOne bidirectional mapping with @JoinColumn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10687529/onetoone-bidirectional-mapping-with-joincolumn)

and then add this line:

```
transcation.setPerson(person);
```

Comment: On Person domain object I changed to  using PrimaryKeyJoinColumn for property transaction . Getting two inserts now but  in the db for tbl_person the foreign key to transaction is null...

Comment: @starcraftOnCrack This link is your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4028091/1526443