# OneToOne mapping with same ids

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I have two entity classes:

```java
@Data @Entity
public class MainEntity {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer mainId;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private SubEntity subEntity;
}
```

and

```java
@Data @Entity
public class SubEntity {

    @Id
    private Integer mainId;
}
```

I found this schema in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10687818/4296219).
I thought it can solve all the problems, but when I tried to save filled `MainEntity` I encountered next exception:

> org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save(): com.example.demo.SubEntity

What am I doing wrong? I don't want to have another primary key in my sub-entity since I use one-to-one mapping. Also I don't need reversed link from `SubEntity` to `MainEntity`.

Code snippet I used to test it:

```java
@Bean
public CommandLineRunner test(MainEntityRepository repo) {
    return args -> {
        MainEntity main = new MainEntity();
        main.setSubEntity(new SubEntity());
        repo.save(main);

        repo.findAll().forEach(System.out::println);
    };
}
```

You can find my sample project on github [here](https://github.com/PloadyFree/one-to-one-subentity-issue).

Comment: If you don't add the Change the `@GeneratedValue` annotation in **SubEntity** class, it doesn't have a way to generate the `id`.

Comment: Considering the title of your question, probably you think that both classes has the same id. That is no true. Both classes/entities have their own id. --- If you do not want to set manually the id for the subEntity, you must define that id as a `@GeneratedValue`. --- If you want a subentity without its own id, you may check the `@Embedded` and `@Embeddable` annotations.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@Data @Entity
public class MainEntity {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer mainId;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "mainEntity", optional = false)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private SubEntity subEntity;
}

@Data @Entity
public class SubEntity {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer mainId;

    @MapsId
    @JoinColumn(name = "mainId")
    @OneToOne(optional = false)
    private MainEntity mainEntity;
}
```

Comment: With the changes you suggested it throws `org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: null id generated for:class com.example.demo.SubEntity`. See here: https://github.com/PloadyFree/one-to-one-subentity-issue/tree/sergey

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you can't insert a PK with a null value, as you have never set the id, hibernate is telling you that you have to do it before saving the entity.

> Solution:
>
> 1- Setting the id manually before saving the Entities.
>
> 2- Anotate the @Id attribute with @GeneratedValue(strategy =
>   GenerationType.IDENTITY) tio auto-generated the value.

Hope this helps.